# GDAL EPSG:4326 Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, epsg-40400

I am converting multiple CSV (Lon, Lat, value) to GeoTIFF. My output is in a different projection (EPSG:404000) using

```
output = 'gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0 -zfield "value" -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l %s %s %s' % (lyr_name, vrt_fn, out_tif)
```

I would like to convert it to EPSG:4326 using each of the following lines alone with no luck. Can I add something to my original output to set the correct projection?

```
output = 'gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:404000 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -l %s %s %s' % (lyr_name, vrt_fn, out_tif)

outputSRS = 'epsg:4326'

output = gdal_translate -projwin_srs epsg:4326
```

Comment: That's not valid Python code. And please state the actual result of your attempt.

Comment: 404000 isn't a valid EPSG (or Esri CRS). Perhaps define it via its proj string instead?

Comment: undefined epsg. This is a valid python code. I have a code that reads all csvs in a folder and converts them to .vrt and .tif. The line before last is the one i posted.

Comment: I want to add something to the gdal_grid code to specify the epsg:4326. The alternative codes I tried, were post code but none worked.

Comment: EPSG:404000 is a pseudo code when there is no projection

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your input file doesn't have a projection. 
The simplest fix is to tell [`gdal_grid`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) what to use as the output projection - `-a_srs epsg:4326`.

Comment: like this? output = 'gdal_grid -a invdist:power=2.0 -zfield "value" -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l -a_srs epsg:4326 %s %s %s' % (lyr_name, vrt_fn, out_tif)

Comment: i tried it and it produced .vrt files but no .tif files.